# Get Dictionary value Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of dictionaries in Python and I want to check if an dictionary entry exists for a specific term. It works using the syntax

```
if any(d['acronym'] == 'lol' for d in loaded_data):
       print "found"
```

but I also want to get the value stored at this key, I mean d['acronym']['meaning']. My problem is that when I try to print it out Python does not know about d. Any suggestions, maybe how can I get the index of the occurence without looping again through all the list? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `filter` function:

```
filter(lambda d: d['acronym'] == 'lol', loaded_data)
```

That will return a list of dictionaries containing `acronym == lol`:

```
l = filter(lambda d: d['acronym'] == 'lol', loaded_data)
if l:
    print "found"
    print l[0]
```

Don't even need to use `any` function at all.

Comment: @Crista23 I'm glad, I updated the question, there's no need for `any` :)

Comment: But that keeps looping even after the first matching dictionary is found, which may or not matter.

Comment: That's true. The OP didn't specify that. DSM answers covers that part with itertator.

Answer (score 3):

If you know there's at most one match (or, alternatively, that you only care about the first) you can use `next`:

```
>>> loaded_data = [{"acronym": "AUP", "meaning": "Always Use Python"}, {"acronym": "GNDN", "meaning": "Goes Nowhere, Does Nothing"}]
>>> next(d for d in loaded_data if d['acronym'] == 'AUP')
{'acronym': 'AUP', 'meaning': 'Always Use Python'}
```

And then depending on whether you want an exception or `None` as the not-found value:

```
>>> next(d for d in loaded_data if d['acronym'] == 'AZZ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-18-27ec09ac3228>", line 1, in <module>
    next(d for d in loaded_data if d['acronym'] == 'AZZ')
StopIteration

>>> next((d for d in loaded_data if d['acronym'] == 'AZZ'), None)
>>>
```

You could even get the value and not the dict directly, if you wanted:

```
>>> next((d['meaning'] for d in loaded_data if d['acronym'] == 'GNDN'), None)
'Goes Nowhere, Does Nothing'
```

Comment: +1 This is a very good approach to not iterating over the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the item, rather than just check that it's there:

```
for d in loaded_data:
    if d['acronym'] == 'lol':
        print("found")
        # use d
        break # skip the rest of loaded_data
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just hoping there's a way of avoiding this stuff! :-)

Comment: The `any` check will do this behind-the-scenes anyway, so it's no less efficient!

Answer (score 0):

`any()` only gives you back a boolean, so you can't use that. So just write a loop:

```
for d in loaded_data:
    if d['acronym'] == 'lol':
        print "found"
        meaning = d['meaning']
        break
else:
    # The else: of a for runs only if the loop finished without break
    print "not found"
    meaning = None
```

Edit: or change it into a slightly more generic function:

```
def first(iterable, condition):
    # Return first element of iterable for which condition is True
    for element in iterable:
        if condition(element):
            return element
    return None

found_d = first(loaded_data, lambda d: d['acronym'] == 'lol')
if found_d:
    print "found"
    # Use found_d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
firstone = next((d for d in loaded_data if d['acronym'] == 'lol'), None)
```

gives you the first dict where the condition applies, or `None` if there is no such dict.